# Limiting number of Wagtail StructBlocks

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I think I'm getting confused over StructBlocks and StreamBlocks in Wagtail, but I can't work out how to limit the number of StructBlocks that can be added to a StreamField in a Page.

```py
from wagtail.core.blocks import CharBlock, StructBlock
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class PersonBlock(StructBlock):
    name = CharBlock(blank=False, required=True)
    bio = CharBlock(blank=True, required=False)

class MyPage(Page):
    leader = StreamField(
        [("leader", PersonBlock(max_num=1))], blank=True
    )

    team = StreamField(
        [("team", PersonBlock())], blank=True
    )

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface(
        [
            ObjectList(
                [StreamFieldPanel("leader"), StreamFieldPanel("team")
            ],
            heading="People"),
        ]
    )
```

I have something like the above, and I only want the user to be able to add a single `PersonBlock` as the `leader`. At the moment they can add multiple. I've tried using `max_num=1` but I think that only applies to `StreamBlock`s, whereas these are `StructBlock`s. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`max_num` is not available on the StructBlock because it describes the behaviour of the *list* of blocks, rather than an individual StructBlock. When you define a StreamField with `StreamField([some set of blocks])`, this list is being handled by an implicit StreamBlock at the top level. `StreamField([some set of blocks])` is really just a shortcut for `StreamField(StreamBlock([some set of blocks]))` - by writing it out in full, you have a place to attach the `max_num` definition:

```
from wagtail.core.blocks import CharBlock, StructBlock, StreamBlock

class MyPage(Page):
    leader = StreamField(
        StreamBlock(
            [("leader", PersonBlock())],
            max_num=1
        ),
        blank=True
    )
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I kept re-reading the docs and I never seemed able to hold on to StreamFields, StreamBlocks and StructBlocks firmly enough. It still lets me add another Leader, but no longer lets me save the page with more than one. Is there a way to stop it letting me add more than one? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong and shouldn't use StreamField/Block for `leader`, only for `team`?

Comment: That feature is coming in Wagtail 2.10, due next week... https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/6070